# Swift 2 Rest API not executing session.dataTaskWithRequest

Tags: xcode, rest, swift2, ios9

Fairly new to Swift.  Trying to execute a simple REST API fetch.  I do not get any errors in the code, however when I watch the code in debug mode the session.DataTaskWithRequest does not seem to execute.

```
<code>
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.learnswiftonline.com/Samples/subway.json")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on /posts/1")
            print(error)
            return
        }
        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
</code>
```

I can hit the url in a browser with not problems and I have even tried other test urls.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had check the code and it will work for me.
The problem is that you need to enable the `App Transport Security` for access the HTTP call in `iOS 9.0` and above. Please find the below steps for how it will added in the application.

> Just right click on the .plist file -> Open As -> Source Code and add
>   the below code in it.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Or if you want to apply to all the URLs.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

For more information please refer Apple’s [Info.plist reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

Hope it works for you!!!